# How to emulate the retry now button in sidekiq

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Using Sidekiq v5.1.3, I have a scenario where a user should ideally be allowed to manually retry a dead job from the "morgue" through a custom dashboard.

I can definitely do this using the "Retry now" button from within Sidekiq's own web UI under the dead tab but I can't figure out how to call this programatically from my own app.

Since the docs explicitly state that:

> The Web UI uses the API exclusively - anything you can do in the UI can be scripted with the API.

I was wondering how to do this using a job's id or any other info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Sidekiq::DeadSet`, this is possible.

For example, you can list all the dead jobs:

```
Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.to_a
```

This will return an Array of `Sidekiq::SortedEntry` instances, which you can run `#retry` on.

Or, you can look up by a single `jid` if you have it:

```
job = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.find_job('02df57719b59ab3a2b3ca3f8')
job.retry
```

This is part of the [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#dead).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!